# ¿Como mostrar elementos fuera de un modal?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

espero me puedan ayudar con este problema que tengo con los estilos estoy tratando de poner un `div` fuera de una modal pero me lo oculta,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo mostrarlo trate de hacerlo con `overflow: visible` pero no me funciono como puedo solucionarlo? dejo mi código aquí, ojala me puedan ayudar :(:

**CSS**

```
.notas{
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#000085;
                background: #ffffcc;
                display:block;
                height:100%;
                width:50%;
                padding:1em;
                list-style:none !important;
                float:left;
                /* border-bottom: 3px solid #FFC300; */
            }

            .tituloNota {
                color: #000;
            }

            .circulo-nota{
                color: #FFC300;
                font-size: 0.5em;
            }

            .lineasNota {
                list-style: none;
                border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFC300;
                height: auto;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                color: #000;
            }

            .cajaNota{
                background-color: #FFC300;
                padding-top: 7px;
                padding-bottom: 7px;
            }

            .notas{
                overflow: auto
            }

            .notasSeguimiento{
                list-style: none;
            }

            .fechaNota{
                font-size: 0.8em;
                text-align: right;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }

        .notaArriba {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0px;
            width: 37.5%;
            z-index: 3000;
            margin-left:-250px;
            overflow-x: visible !important;
            overflow-y: visible !important;
        }
```

**JS**

```
$("#modalSeguimiento").iziModal({
        headerColor: '#00A4DC',
        overlayClose: false,
        width: '75%',
        zindex: 2600
    });
```

**MODAL**

```
<div id="modalSeguimiento" style="right: -255px;" class="m-cerrar" data-izi Modal-fullscreen="false"  data-iziModal-title="Seguimiento de la petición - {{ $claveAccion }}" data-iziModal-icon="far fa-file-alt"> 
    <!-- Contenido -->
    <div class="container">
        <br>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="tabsleft-tab4">
                    <hr>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <p> El trámite <b>18/15/000010673</b> se encuentra en proceso de validación por el comité.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <span class="porciento-80"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> 80%</span>
                                <hr class="progress-hr">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="notaArriba">
            <div class="container" style="background-color: #ffffcc; border: 1px solid #FFC300!important;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 cajaNota">
                        <h5 class="tituloNota"><center><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> Observación</center></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="fechaNota">10/11/2018 10:00 PM </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="notasSeguimiento">
                                <p class="lineasNota">
                                    <i class="fas fa-circle circulo-nota"></i> EL solicitante Bibiana Cortes Rios llamo para verificar como se encontraba el proceso del tramite solicitado.
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El overflow debe ir en la clase **iziModal**

```
.iziModal {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba @Erick Patrick